# Prototype cell style ignored in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm working on my first iOS project. It features a UITableView that shows data I get from a web service and puts it into single UITableViewCells.

In the storyboard, I changed the style of the prototype cell to 'Subtitle' and in my viewController I added a line of code where I set the subtitle, however if I run the app the cells are still using the default style and the subtitle isn't shown.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *departure = self.departures[indexPath.row];
NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ in %@ Min", departure[@"train"], departure[@"dest"], departure[@"time"]];
cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test"; //this line is being ignored

return cell;

}
```

I tried the same thing using the master-detail template provided by Xcode and there it actually worked, so I guess that I messed up somewhere (possibly something quite stupid), but I can't seem to find the mistake.

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause that problem. Did you register the class by any chance?

Comment: That was it! At the beginning I 'borrowed' some code from a book on iOS Programming and along the way I somehow forgot to remove the register-class call.
Thank you very much!